# In custom UITableView-- Value of type 'AnyObject->()'has no member 'tag' error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a problem with making a custom UITableViewCell .

The problem is, in my custom class I have my buttons code with sender 'AnyObject' :

```
@IBAction func checkBox(sender: AnyObject) {
    }
```

In my main ViewController I have my function for changing some stuff in my cell :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:ingredientCell = self.ingredientTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! ingredientCell

        cell.inCellLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
        cell.checkBox.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.checkBox.addTarget(self, action: Selector("yourButtonClicked:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        return cell
    }
```

Xcode saying in my cell.checkBox.tag and cell.checkBox.addTarget lines ***Value of type 'AnyObject->()'has no member 'tag'*** I really could not understand and couldn't find any solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`checkBox` is a function, and you're treating it like a property.  If you want a reference to your `checkBox` view, whatever that may be, you need to create an `@IBOutlet` property for it that is connected in the storyboard and use that instead of your `@IBAction` function.

Instead of

```
@IBAction func checkBox(sender: AnyObject) {}
```

You need

```
@IBOutlet weak var checkBox: UIButton!
```

Comment: @nhgrif Sure, although it's not strictly necessary.  I'll add it for good measure.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've hooked your `checkBox` up as an `IBAction` but not as an `IBOutlet`.  The error message you're getting is indicating that the `IBAction` method doesn't have a "tag" property.

What you probably intended to do was hook the check box up as an `IBOutlet`, then that property should have a "tag" property.