# View tableview cell text on table view cell button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a table view where I have created a label and two buttons. I am stuck while getting the text from the label on button click. I have created an array list like:

```
let arrayList: [String] = [ "aaa" , "bbb" , "ccc"]
```

I want if I click the button on `index[0]` I shall get "aaa" and if `index[2]` I shall get "ccc"

[image]

```
@IBOutlet weak var titleLable: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var infoButton: UIButton!

myCell.titleLable.text = self.arrayList[indexPath.row]
myCell.infoButton.tag = indexPath.row
myCell.infoButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: Your action isn't with params,pass button to it and then from button tag you can get "aaa" or "ccc".

Comment: i already did that but i want to display the corresponding text with the info button click

Comment: give the tag to both buttons from storyboards and in your swift file, then check if button clicked with that tag in if conditions and than assign array elements in title text of button using array property of firstObject and lastObject. @SajjadAims

Answer (score 1):

Try to get `indexPath`, where the button is clicked using the Button Tag.

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath.init(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0))
    cell.myLabel.text = arrayList[sender.tag]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to do like

**swift3**

```
myCell.titleLable.text = self.arrayList[indexPath.row]
myCell.infoButton.tag = indexPath.row
myCell.infoButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourVCName.buttonClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

get action as

```
 @IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton){

     print(self.arrayList[sender. tag])

}
```

**Swift2**

```
myCell.titleLable.text = self.arrayList[indexPath.row]
myCell.infoButton.tag = indexPath.row
myCell.infoButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)


@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton){

     print(self.arrayList[sender. tag])

}
```

Comment: value of button have no member tag,

Comment: You need

@IBOutlet weak var infoButton: UIButton!

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33662020/in-custom-uitableview-value-of-type-anyobject-has-no-member-tag-error

Answer (score 1):

**In your Table View Controller**

```
let dataSource: [String] = [ "aaa" , "bbb" , "ccc"]

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(YourCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourCell
    let title = dataSource[indexPath.row]
    cell.setup(withTitle: title, delegate: self)
    return cell
}

// MARK: - Your Cell Delegate
func didTapActionButton(fromCell cell: UITableViewCell) {
    if let indexPath = itemTable.indexPathForCell(cell) {
        let selectedItem = dataSource[indexPath.row]
        print(selectedItem)
    }
}
```

**In your Table View Cell**

Firstly, define a protocol:

```
protocol YourTableViewCellDelegate {
    func didTapActionButton(fromCell cell: UITableViewCell)
}
```

And then:

```
// MARK: - Properties
var delegate: YourTableViewCellDelegate?

// MARK: - @IBOutlets
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var infoButton: UIButton!

// MARK: - @IBActions
@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.didTapActionButton(fromCell: self)
}

// MARK: - Public Methods
func setup(withTitle title: title, delegate: YourTableViewCellDelegate?) {
    titleLabel.text = title
    self.delegate = delegate
}
```