# Name button on custom cell, show profile - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am having the hardest time trying to figure out, how I get a button working, on my custom cell? Since I cannot use performSegue in a custom cell? How can I do that, can anyone tell me how you would do it?

Hope you can :-)

Sorry for no code!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585638/get-indexpath-of-uitableviewcell-on-click-of-button-from-cell/39585749#39585749 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39716304/view-tableview-cell-text-on-table-view-cell-button/39716407#39716407

Comment: I would also be able to send a string of data with that though? And I see no prepareForSegue to do that? :/

Answer (score 1):

are you want to push on another controller when click on profile button ?

So you need to implement a delegate method for button action than you can push on another controller.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do :) I need to be sending a string to the other uitableviewcontroller.. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: you need to implement custom delegate in your custom cell class.

Comment: Sorry but I do not know how to do that

Comment: you can see link by Mr Ub